Powerpoint VBA inquiry : Sound after Trigger
Good morning.
I'm testing a Powerpoint vba code in c#.
My goal is to trigger a shape to rotate by 90 degree with sound effect.
Here's my code (C#)
`Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Effect pEffect;

slide.Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, 50, 50, 100, 100);
slide.Shapes[1].Name = "Rectangle";

pEffect = slide.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences.Add().AddTriggerEffect(slide.Shapes[1], MsoAnimEffect.msoAnimEffectSpin, MsoAnimTriggerType.msoAnimTriggerOnShapeClick, slide.Shapes[1]);
pEffect.Timing.TriggerDelayTime = 0;
pEffect.Timing.Duration = 0.3f;
pEffect.EffectParameters.Amount = 90;`

Until I put sound effect, this code seems to work fine. I can see it in the Animation Timeline(InteractiveSequences)
pic1. Code seems to be working
After this, I wanted to add Sound effect. ( The sound file is in "c:\temp\test.wav" ),
But the problem happens from here.
I tried various codes but failed wasting hours in vain.
I tested various codes but I don't know how to play sound effects together with trigger.
Some of the codes I used are like..
slide.Shapes[1].AnimationSettings.SoundEffect.ImportFromFile("c:\temp\test.wav")

or

Shape soundShape = slide.Shapes.AddMediaObject2("test.wav", MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoCTrue,0,0,0,0);
soundShape.Name = "wavSound";
soundShape.MediaFormat.Volume = 0.5f;

or

soundEffect = slide.Shapes[1].AnimationSettings.SoundEffect;
soundEffect.ImportFromFile("test.wav");

These codes did not work at all and it already working previous effect disappear.

I don't know why sound effect code make the previous effect disappear.

How can I play sound effect together with trigger?
What I'd like to do is... accessing to blue area in the picture to play sound effect.
pic2. How can I access to blue area by code?


Any advice will be welcome.
Thank you for your advice in advance.
